# Referencing a cell with multiple variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have defined 2 variables string and integer respectively. Using both the variable in need to reference a cell and pluck the data. Could anyone help in doing this?

```
With Page 3

.activate
Dim OracleProjType as String -> stores the value "C"
Dim SearchProjNameRow as Integer -> Stores the value "6"
Dim OracleProjTypeData as string -> Stores the data of "C6" cell

OracleProjTypeData = .Range(" " & OracleProjType & ":" & SearchProjNameRow).Value  -> Getting an error here as "Run time error 1004, Application - Object defined error"

End with
```

Comment: Why would `" C:6"` be a valid range?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TEST()

    Dim OracleProjType As String
    Dim SearchProjNameRow As Long
    Dim OracleProjTypeData As String

    OracleProjType = "C" '<==Assign the value to the variable
    SearchProjNameRow = 6

    With Worksheets("Sheet3") '<== Work with that sheet using with so no activate
        OracleProjTypeData = .Range(OracleProjType & SearchProjNameRow).Value '<==Concatenate values to create range reference
        Debug.Print OracleProjTypeData
    End With
End Sub
```